# How to throw error or timeout promise if there is no response within x seconds Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React project that has a function which returns a promise. I am looking for a way to make the function throw an error if the promise does not return anything from the network within 10 seconds.

```
const get = async (options) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const results = axios(options)
      resolve(results.data)

      // We we don't get results back within 10 seconds then error or return empty array[]
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: 1. axios already returns a promise, you don't have to wrap it in a promise 2. axios has timeout option you can use

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.race` in combination with a `setTimeout`:

```
const result = await Promise.race(
    [
        get, // your function that you don't want to spend too much time waiting on
        new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(
            () => {
                reject("Did not receive results within 10s")
            }, 10 * 1000)
        )
    ]);
```